# TeamCity - replace some files before publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc, teamcity, web-deployment

In my ASP.NET MVC project I need to set up deploying via TeamCity 2017.2.1 but the problem is the use of third-party libraries that have a separate version for deployment. Is it possible to set up TeamCity to replace some `bin` files with specified ones after successful build and before deployment?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43556952/)

Comment: You could add Command Line build step and xcopy all required files to bin folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before, you can use Command Line build step, where you can replace your dependencies using copy command. However, I would suggest reconsider this approach as it might impose some risks. It means that your code will be deployed with different dependency than it was built and tested against. Why not referencing the same version of the dependency that will be used in production?